# How can I generate an inheritance chart in C#? Are there any free tools?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, inheritance

How can I generate an inheritance chart in C#?
I have a lot of classes in this project and it would be useful.

Edit: I have VS2008

Comment: Do you have a version of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, right-click in Solution Explorer, select "Add..." then "New Item" and select "Class Diagram" from the options presented. Then you can just drag in the classes you're interested in - either from your solution or the object browser.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on your project, select Add -> New Item -> Class Diagram.

Answer (score 0):

[AutoDiagrammer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AutoDiagrammer.aspx) plug-in for [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) will do this as well.